# Programmatically Find Out Type of Mounted Drive - Mac OSX

Tags: macos, external, mount, drive, diskarbitration

It doesn't seem that DiskArbitration framework provides a way to find out the device type (network drive, external drives, etc). Is there any other way to programmatically figure out the type of a mounted device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a CFDictonary from DADiskCopyDescription, kDADiskDescriptionVolumeKindKey key gives a reasonable idea of the type